# Force SubClasses to @Override method from SuperClass. Method in SuperClass must have body

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract, overriding

I would like to force `SubClasses` to `@Override` method from `SuperClass`.

Method in `SuperClass` can't be `abstract`, cause I wanna provide some basic implementation.

Here is example of my code:

```
public abstract class GenericModel<T extends GenericModel> {
    long id, counter;

    public String methodToBeOverridenInSubClass(String name) {
        // some basic implementation
        // rest details will be provided by subclass
        return name;
    }

}
public class SubClass extends GenericModel<SubClass> {
    @Override
    public String methodToBeOverridenInSubClass(String name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "name": return "Real name";
            default: super.methodToBeOverridenInSubClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

This post is interesting:
[MustOverrideException and MethodNotOverridenException](http://www.coderanch.com/t/399096/java/java/force-method-overriden-subclasses)

Please give me some help

Comment: You cannot force a subclass to override if the superclass method is not abstract.

Comment: I know this. I am looking for some workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what your are looking for is resolved by [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). 
In which you create a parent class with one method implemented which describe a process that calls anothers methods (steps). These steps are abstract so they are implemented by a sub class.

Example from wikipedia:

```
/**
* An abstract class that is common to several games in
* which players play against the others, but only one is
* playing at a given time.
*/

abstract class Game {

protected int playersCount;
abstract void initializeGame();
abstract void makePlay(int player);
abstract boolean endOfGame();
abstract void printWinner();

/* A template method : */
public final void playOneGame(int playersCount) {
    this.playersCount = playersCount;
    initializeGame();
    int j = 0;
    while (!endOfGame()) {
        makePlay(j);
        j = (j + 1) % playersCount;
    }
    printWinner();
}
}

//Now we can extend this class in order 
//to implement actual games:

class Monopoly extends Game {

/* Implementation of necessary concrete methods */
void initializeGame() {
    // Initialize players
    // Initialize money
}
void makePlay(int player) {
    // Process one turn of player
}
boolean endOfGame() {
    // Return true if game is over 
    // according to Monopoly rules
}
void printWinner() {
    // Display who won
}
/* Specific declarations for the Monopoly game. */

// ...
}

class Chess extends Game {

/* Implementation of necessary concrete methods */
void initializeGame() {
    // Initialize players
    // Put the pieces on the board
}
void makePlay(int player) {
    // Process a turn for the player
}
boolean endOfGame() {
    // Return true if in Checkmate or 
    // Stalemate has been reached
}
void printWinner() {
    // Display the winning player
}
/* Specific declarations for the chess game. */

// ...
}
```

Comment: This seems not the correct answer for the question. The subclass is required to be forced to implement one of the superClass's method which has a body.

Comment: A little late but I think this is correct. The subclass needs to define the "partial" methods initializeGame(), endOfGame(), etc., in order for the playOneGame(int) method to do its work. The subclass, of course, will call the playOneGame(int) method once the other methods are defined.

Answer (score 4):

You can use two methods:

```
public abstract String methodToBeOverridenInSubClass(String name);


protected String commonMethodToUseInSubClasses(String name) {
    // some basic implementation
    return name;
}
```

This way the subclass must override `methodToBeOverridenInSubClass` but you can still use common code for all sub-classes in `commonMethodToUseInSubClasses`.

Comment: So in `SubClass` I will override `methodToBeOverridenInSubClass`. Then in that method body i will call `methodToUse` from `SuperClass`?

Comment: You gave me good answer that solves my issue. So Thanks very much. But [Ezequiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2547753/ezequiel)  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31020440/2794446) is more detailed So I am obligated to accept his answer.