# How to force a subClass to implement a method in superClass which has body

Tags: java, android, overwrite

```
Class Base{
    public void doThings(){
         //some logic that needed by subclass
    }
}

Class A extends Base{
      public void doThings(){
         super.doThings();
         doOtherThings();
    }
}
```

What I want is to force A to overwrite doThings() method(there will be error message if not) and call super.doThings(); but doThings() in Base should not be abstract for it has body.

Is there any decent solutions? I found the same question in below link but the accepted answer does not answer it right.
[Force SubClasses to @Override method from SuperClass. Method in SuperClass must have body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020048/force-subclasses-to-override-method-from-superclass-method-in-superclass-must)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make sure that doThings of the base class is called, you should design your class like this:

```
abstract class Base {
  public void doThings() {
    // do some things here
    ...
    // make sure subclass does some things too
    methodYouMustImplement();
  }

  abstract void methodYouMustImplement();
}

class A extends Base {
  @Override void methodYouMustImplement() {
    // do some other things
  }
}
```

This way, A is forced to give a implementation of methodYouMustImplement() and it is guaranteed by design that your code in doThings() is called without the need to *remember* to call super.doThings().
You could then consider making doThings() final, as Andy Turner suggested.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this is different to my answer, other than the fact that you've opted not to make `doThings()` final.

Comment: Sorry I dont see how "do some things"  is ensured to be called by implement methodYouMustImplement.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is with your edited implementation. Your previous implementation did not call methodYouMustImplement from within doThings().

Comment: @tainy it's not assured here. That's the point of making `doThings` `final`.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be easier to use a construct such as:

```
public class Base {

     public void doStuff() {
         doSpecificStuff();
         // do base stuff every one has to do
     }

     abstract void doSpecificStuff();
}

public class WeirdlySpecific extends Base {

    public void doSpecificStuff() {
        // specific stuff happens
    }
}
```

This does not force `WeirdlySpecific` to actually implement the `doStuff()` method, but as long as `doStuff()` is called as a contract by any caller, each more specific implementation has its own version of events.

Answer (score 2):

A requirement to call the super method is [considered an anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super); that aside, the only way you can *force* a subclass to implement a method is to make it abstract.

If you want `super.doThings()` to be called first, and then subclass-specific stuff to be run after, turn the problem around:

- Make `doThings()` final
- Add an `abstract` method that is called within `doThings()`.

Something like this:

```
abstract class Base {
  public final void doThings() {
    methodYouMustImplement();

    // Stuff after subclass-specific implementation.
  }

  abstract void methodYouMustImplement();
}

class A extends Base {
  @Override void methodYouMustImplement() {
    doOtherThings();
  }
}
```

The fact that `doThings()` is `final` is important to the requirements: this guarantees that the things you want to happen when `doThings()` is invoked, because no subclass can change this method. If you leave it non-final, subclasses can decide to override `doThings()`, meaning that `methodYouMustImplement()` (and any other actions you specify in `doThing()`) are not necessarily called.

Comment: `The only way you can force a subclass to implement a method is to make it final`. Well you made `doThings()` final, but does it mean that I as a user of your class have to implement it?

Comment: @azizbekian no, because it's final. You have to implement `methodYouMustImplement` (or make `A` `abstract` also).

Comment: but doThings is not mandatory to be overwrited, this is not what I want. And make it final makes no sense

Comment: @tainy The only way to force a class to implement a method is to make it abstract. That's just how Java is.

Comment: @AndyTurner so there is no way to meet my requirement. so sad. For this is quite useful for some situation

Comment: This is the correct answer.  @tainy I'm not sure, but maybe what you're missing is that if you don't override doThings(), then whoever calls doThings() on Base subclasses will be calling Base.doThings(), which effectively achieves what you want.